# Azure portal fox bing ads sandbox api

Tags: azure, azureportal, bing-ads-api

I was managing my sandbox bingads application for test purposes at https://apps.dev.microsoft-int.com/#/appList. The page has info, that it will no longer be supported soon and azure portal should be used. When I am going to this azure portal my account is not working there.

Is there a "-int" version of azure portal as well where my account will be working?

Answer (score 1):

If the app was created with in [apps.dev.microsoft-int](https://apps.dev.microsoft-int.com/#/appList), you should be able to view the applications at [this](https://df.onecloud.azure-test.net/) link of Azure Portal.

Hope the above information helps.